# Is it possible to define a list of queues where each queue can be of different types?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to define a class where the main element is a list of queues.

The problem is that each queue can be of different types.

Here is an example of what I would like to get. If we define these queues:

```
queue1 (type int)    = {5,7,3,4,5}
queue2 (type string) = {"Sam","Peter"}
queue3 (type string) = {"January","February","March"}
queue4 (type int)    = {10}
```

Then, I would like to be able to create objects like these:

```
object1.list_of_queues = {queue1,queue2}
object2.list_of_queues = {queue2,queue3,queue4}
```

All of them based on the same class.

I am able to create a type "list of queues", but all of them share the same type:

```
typedef std::queue<std::string> queue_type; //queue of strings
typedef std::list<queue_type> list_type;    //list of queues of (only) strings
```

Is there any solution without using lists to avoid this type mixing? I was thinking about encapsulating the queues into a new defined type. Or creating a list of pointers, where every pointer points to the right queue, but I don't know if this is possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps look at templates.  Or use `std::variant`.  Hard to advise otherwise without a better idea of the actual problem you need to solve.  Potential XY Problem at play here.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I am sorry if my question is not 100% clear. I just want to be able create objects from the same class, that can be "upgraded" without modifying the original class by adding or removing elements to the lists.

Comment: For example, I would be able create the class "shape" where I could define all these objects:
squares, coloured_squares or circles all from the same class "shape". The only difference will be the elements in the lists. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You seems to talk about [inheritance](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/112-basic-inheritance-in-c/). Where you want your `circle`, `square`, etc to derive from a parent class `shape`, but I dont understand the `queue` part. You need a queue of shape ?

Comment: The problem that I find with inheritance is that if you have hundreds (just to give a big number) of small variations for the same class, you need to define a new class for each one of them. The queue part is to be able to store more variants and make the class as general as possible. The idea would be to be able to fully define a new object when it is created, instead of writing a new class that inherits from the original one, and then create the new object.

Comment: But the original question supposes you already have some collection of different types you want to put in the queues. (These control aspects of behavior of the objects you want to create?) Can those types use polymorphic inheritance to store as a common type?

Comment: @Marcos You try to use strong typed langage as C++ and use it as an untyped language as Java. Usually, you should write code according to the philosophy of the language. While at first, it might seem simpler, in the end using `variant` would probably make the application slower and harder to maintains. While it might be useful in some specific cases, you overall design you follow C++ nature of strong typed types. You should not be afraid of having a lot of classes. You also need to figure out if you want to use static (templates) or dynamic polymorphism (virtual functions).

Comment: @Phil1970 You are completely right. This idea about creating a "general" class may look simpler conceptually, but maybe it is not the best solution to implement in C++. I think that I was trying make an abstraction by creating a "meta-class" to avoid what is the natural solution: to create all the necessary classes that you need (even if it is a lot of them).

Comment: What version of C++ are you on? That affects the answer, as since C++17 (I think) `std::any` would make this a breeze.

Comment: Yes, it is [since C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to define a list of queues where each queue can be of different types?

Not directly.

A `std::queue` of one element type is a different type from a queue of another element type. `std::list` is a homogeneous container: All elements have the same type.

What you can do is have a list or queue of a type-erasing wrapper such as `std::variant` or `std::any` which can contain objects of a type from correspondingly limited, or unlimited selection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I suspect you want to do something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double area() const = 0;
};


class Circle : public Shape
{
    double radius;
public:
    Circle(const double r) : radius(r) {}
    double area() const {
        return 3.1416 * radius * radius;
    }
};


class Square : public Shape
{
    double side;
public:
    Square(const double s) : side(s) {}
    double area() const {
        return side * side;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> my_list;
    my_list.push_back(std::make_unique<Circle>(2.0));
    my_list.push_back(std::make_unique<Square>(4.0));

    for(const auto& el : my_list)
        std::cout << el->area() << std::endl;
}
```

Where I used polymorphism/inheritance to create an object of type `Shape`. Then Im using a list of that parent object as `pointer`, so it possible to create different child elements such as `Cirlce` or `Square`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are ways to do this. This utilities both runtime and compile time polymorphism. My favorite utilities the following types.
C++ like pseudo-code follows:

```
#include <typeinfo>

namespace dynamics {

class AnyBase {
     virtual const type_info& getTypeInfo();
     virtual ~AnyBase()
}

template<typename T>
class DynamicAny : public AnyBase {
     type_info typekind;
     T val;

     template<typename T>
     DynamicAny(const T& t) : typekind(typeof(T)), val(t) {}

     //... usual move/copy constructors/operators follow

     //conversion operators
     inline operator T&() {
          return val;
     }
     inline operator const T&() const {
          return val;
     }

     //possibly comparison operators with const T& too...

     //virtual call for type information for this type
     const type_info& getTypeInfo() {
           return typekind;
     }
}

}
```

You could then include any `std::unique_ptr<AnyBase>` within a vector or queue or any data structure for that matter. But assign it a `DynamicAny<T>` of the desired type. Then when you get it out of that data structure simply call `getTypeInfo()` on the `AnyBase` to determine which `DynamicAny<T>` to cast it to.
See `type_info` for more details.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/

You could also use `std::any` that does a similar thing.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any
c++17 only onward.

```
typedef std::queue<std::unique_ptr<AnyBase>> queue_type; //queue of unique_ptr of DynamicAny<T>
typedef std::list<queue_type> list_type;    //list of queues of (only) strings
```